# $\left\Vert J(x)^{-1}\right\Vert<2\left\Vert J(x^*)^{-1}\right\Vert. $?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis

Could you please help me to prove this theorem:

Suppose  $J:{\bf {\rm R}}^m\rightarrow{\bf {\rm R}}^{n\times n}$ is a continuous matrix-valued function. If J(x*) is nonsingular, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for all  $x\in{\bf {\rm R}}^m$ with  $\Vert x-x^*\Vert<\delta$, J(x) is nonsingular and 
$\left\Vert J(x)^{-1}\right\Vert<2\left\Vert J(x^*)^{-1}\right\Vert.
$

since J is nonsingular, it is bijective. for a compact set, the inverse of J is also continuous.

From here I need to show the boundedness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that should easily follow from continuity. There is a theorem about the inverse of a continuous function being continuous as well (edit: Oh, you even added that piece of info with an edit). So $J(x)^{-1}$ is continuous and therefore

$$\|J(x)^{-1} - J(x^*)^{-1}\| < \varepsilon \ .$$

when

$$\|x-x^*\| < \delta$$

where $\delta$ is a function of $\varepsilon$. For sufficiently small $\varepsilon$, we can assume $\varepsilon \leq \|J(x^*)^{-1}\|$ (For non-zero RHS. Does the non-singularity guarantee that? I'm not sure.). Then

$$\|J(x)^{-1} - J(x^*)^{-1}\| < \|J(x^*)^{-1}\| $$

or

$$\|J(x)^{-1} - J(x^*)^{-1}\| + \|J(x^*)^{-1}\| < 2\|J(x^*)^{-1}\| $$

and with the triangle inequality

$$\|J(x)^{-1} - J(x^*)^{-1} + J(x^*)^{-1}\| < 2\|J(x^*)^{-1}\| $$
$$\|J(x)^{-1}\| < 2\|J(x^*)^{-1}\| $$

I hope there is no flaw in my reasoning, let me know if you find one.